# Backing Object not removed after Form submission in Spring Mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC-3 , when we do a form submit, the form backing object does not get removed.
I thought in spring mvc, it removes the baking object after a form submit.

Am I correct or Can anyone explain what might have happened here ?

PS

```
<form:form id="id1" commandName="command1" modelAttribute="command1" method="post">
```

When we do a submit, that model attribute binned to the form get removed at some point from the session doesn't it?.

What I want to know is that point at where the command object get removed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide some code. Might be a bug there.. MVC actually does not have a backing object. All you can do is put objects into the model map and they get deleted after each request. When you do a form post, all Spring MVC does is to map your form inputs to the object you have in your controller:

form:

```
<form action="/some-path" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="some_property"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/some-path" method = RequestMethod.POST)   
public ModelAndView createItem(SomeObject someObject, BindingResult result) {
// ...
}
```

mapping object:

```
public class SomeObject {

    private String some_property;

    // getter, setter

}
```

If you didn't declare your object as a Bean (`@Named`, `@Component` or something) or added it to the model map:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.addObject("someObject,someObject);
```

then it'll be gone when the controller is finished.

**edit**
Didn't notice the jsp tag.. Don't think it changes much.. Still, without any code it's hard to say anything for certain.